# Why index not working on non-unique datetime column?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Table struct:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `stat_old` (
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `offer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `dt` (`dt`,`offer_id`,`aff_id`),
  KEY `dt_2` (`dt`),
  KEY `offer_id` (`offer_id`),
  KEY `aff_id` (`aff_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

the `dt` field stores datetime values cast to hour like '2019-01-01 01:00:00', '2019-01-01 02:00:00', and its non unique.

query:

```sql
explain select *
FROM stat_old
WHERE
  dt between '2019-02-11 16:00:00' and '2019-02-18 15:59:59'
order by dt;
```

result:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stat_old | ALL  | dt,dt_2       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 18914072 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

As you can see, it nearly scan the full table which has 20,044,835 rows. Actually the result data has only 2,108,707 rows. Why index on `dt` is not using ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: MySQL will not choose to use the index if your search covers a large enough part of the table. If you search for a smaller date range, I bet it will use the index.

Comment: try this: ```WHERE = '2019-02-11 16:00:00'``` you will see the index is used.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes you are right ! Thank you! so it's not possible to optimize it ?

Comment: It is an optimization. To fetch each `dt` value in the range using an index and then go back to the main table and pull each of those entries out is often slower that just scanning the table. Also recommend changing your unique key to a primary key. As a primary key, scanning the PK will get all the fields and can be done as a range, even if large. Also recommend removing `dt_2` (is cover by the prefix of the key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making `dt` the first part of the primary key will help when retrieving a larger date range in `dt` order:

```
alter table stat_old
drop key dt,
drop key dt_2,
add primary key (`dt`,`offer_id`,`aff_id`)
```

Comment: Caveat:  This forces `offer_id` and `aff_id` to be `NOT NULL`.  If that is OK, then this is the "optimization" you are looking for.